# using exec and compile in python

Tags: python, dictionary, compilation, exec

I want to have a dictionary where the value is a statement.  I don't need to build the statement dynamically.  The names appearing in the statement are in the local scope. A simple example appears below.  It seems like 'exec' is the thing to use, but this appears to be frowned upon, and is probably slow.  This code will be used in a stochastic modeler, and will be run gazillions of times.  Could you suggest to me how to best accomplish this idea (maybe by precompiling?).  Could it be I already have this right?

Cheers!

Jeff

```
d={'plusone':'x+=1','minusone':'x-=1'}
x=2
exec(d['plusone'])
print x  ::: output '3'
exec(d['minusone'])
print x  ::: output '2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are doing `exec(d['plusone'])` in some scope wherein `x` is defined, otherwise you would get a `NameError`.

It seems far better to put a callable into your `dict` and explicitly pass it `x` (and explicitly assign to `x`):

```
from operator import add, sub

d={'plusone':lambda x: add(x,1), 'minusone':lambda x: sub(x,1)}

x = 2

x = d['plusone'](x)

x
Out[17]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks.  The key was to use the lambda function and pass the parameter to it.  Now a question about speed:  will this be fast?  I suppose so, since the bytecode is just compiled once - the first time the function gets called?

Comment: @VortexProf yes, should be rather fast since you only have to compile once.  Importing the operators may or may not help performance, it allows you flexibility, though.  You could i.e. just put the bare operator `add` in the dict and then do something like `d['plus'](x,1)` to achieve the same thing as your `plusone` op, with the flexibility that it can be plus-any-number.